# Why do attr_accessor virtual attributes not get outputted when you do record.inspect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my ListItem rails model I have:

```
attr_accessor :catalyst_action, :actor_user_id, :actor_full_name
```

I'm able to set these variables in the controller and I confirmed that when the record gets to the observer they are still there.

**Controller**

```
  @list_item.actor_user_id = current_user.id
  @list_item.actor_full_name = current_user.full_name
  @list_item.save
```

**Observer**

```
  Rails.logger.info '@list_item.inspect - ListItemObserver'
  Rails.logger.info record.inspect
  Rails.logger.info record.actor_user_id
  Rails.logger.info record.actor_full_name
  Rails.logger.info '@list_item.inspect - ListItemObserver'
```

These output just fine, but when I do the record.inspect the virtual attr are not being outputted, but if I log them specifically they are there and output. Why does outputting record not include the vattr? How can I get record to include these variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are virtual attributes, not real attributes. Active Record provides the `inspect` method ([definition is here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb#L837-848)) and it iterates through all the columns of the model which obviously don't include the virtual attributes.

If you want to find out what the virtual attributes are on the model then there's no easy way to do that. You would have to assign them into a list somewhere and then read from that list.

Comment: How can I output them? Given record. I want to output record with 2 virtual attributes? Is there a way?

Comment: In my observer I tried record.merge({ :actor_user_id => record.actor_user_id, :actor_full_name => record.actor_full_name }) but that failed with undefined method `merge' for #<ListItem:0x00000104ab13c8

Comment: First: No, there is not a way. Follow my advice in the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Second: you're attempting to merge into the record and not the attributes for the record. You want to do `record.attributes.merge`.