# how to make a ActiveModel to became a hash or array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
 class Post< ActiveRecord::Base                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 end   

post_array = Post.first
```

If I want to add some data into p.

```
post_array['test'] = nil
```

this will make errors:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute \`ff'
        from ......rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/write.rb:34:in `write_attribute'
```

I think the reason is : [this commit in github: Raise error when using write_attribute with a non-existent attribute](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/50d395f96ea05da1e02459688e94bff5872c307b)

How can I insert some data into post_array , ie, `post_array['test'] = nil`?

Maybe there is some methods can convert this ActiveModel into hash or array?

Comment: Your title refers to ActiveRecord, but your body refers to ActiveModel.  Can you clarify what you are trying to do and show the Post class?

Comment: thanks, I think it's ActiveModel. However, I did'nt even know what's difference between ActiveRecrod and ActiveModel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this like so:

```
post = Post.first
hash = post.attributes
hash['test'] = 'test'
```

However you probably don't want to: I imagine you're struggling here with needing to store some data on an object, and models are all about storing data on themselves. If you want this data persisted to your datastore, you should write a migration that includes this column. If not, then you should use attr_accessor in your model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :test

end

post.test = 'test' # Now assigns 'test' to post correctly, and you can read it out the same way.
```

Generally unless you're converting the model's data to a different format (like JSON or plist or something), changing it into a hash will usually just make your life more difficult.

Comment: thanks you, @Veraticus !  It helps a lot. But I still have a further question.  If `post.test = 'test'`.  It's OK.   `puts post.test` will return `'test'`.  But `pp post` won't see `post.test` . Why ?

Comment: I'm not sure what version of Ruby you're using, but pp should try to get instance variables as well... perhaps Rails does something with pp preventing this? If you want an answer to that question, I would post it again on Stackoverflow. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Veraticus , I also find the [reason](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7884703/1232102) in stackoverflow. Thanks your help. :D